# SSL certificate is showing issuer[Issued by] as mydomain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I was looking at few sites and their SSL certificate and I noticed that few SSL certificates shows Issuer[Issued by] as mydomain[myorganisation]

Example sites showing issuer as mydomain
https://www.akamai.com/
https://letsencrypt.org/

Is this some type of certificate, Can someone explain this !

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or two? The Issuer/ Issued By for https://www.akamai.com is "Verizon Akamai SureServer CA G14-SHA2" and for https://letsencrypt.org is "TrustID Server CA A52".

Comment: You probably have some device (Proxy, firewall) in your network or a program on your computer (like mcafee) that issues certificates on the fly. They use it to inspect SSL traffic.

Comment: @Pepo you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

`mydomain.com` is a certificate authority (CA) among other things. So they sign certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your answer @ EJP

But I just mentioned mydomain to represent my company's domain name and not mydomain.com

Also now I've checked these sites using Firefox and Internet explorer and now the Issuer is different ! [ Previously I only used chrome]
I guess it's something with the browser i'm using.

## Resolved

We have a firewall and there is also a certificate that needs to be imported in order to access 'https' sites !